# Implementing a diary system to store the current note/indexed note to a diary array

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate/move/add the current index note to the diary array using the AddNotesToDiary Function. The indexed note should be removed from the notes array when moved to the diary array. I have the idea, though i can't figure out the way forward.

```
//list of Notes
public string[] notes;
public int index; //which current note available
public string currentNote;

//Collected Notes or Diary
public string[] Diary;

private void Start()
{
    //current note in the index
    currentNote = notes[index];
}

private void Update()
{
    //current note in the index
    currentNote = notes[index];
}

private void AddNotesToDiary()
{
    //how to instantiate/move/add the note[index] to the Diary[]

}
```

Comment: Presumably you don't want to use arrays. Arrays are good for fixed size sets. You are talking about moving things so changing the size of notes and Diary. Switch to a List<string> for example and you get functionality like Add/Remove in that List class that you can use in AddNotesToDiary then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could replace the `string[]` with `List<string>`. this would let you add and remove from the notes and diary:

```
notes.Remove(currentNote);
Diary.Add(currentNote);
```